# How can I remove the double space after a div tag in TCPDF?

Tags: php, tcpdf

How can I remove the double space after a div tag in TCPDF?

For example:

```
<p>Text1</p>
<div> 
    <h2> Heading</h2> 
     <p>Text2</p>
</div>
<p>Text3</p>
```

In between Div and Text, when it outputs, I have a double space like this:

```
Text2


Text3
```

I tried using `setHtmlVSpace` to remove the space from the `div` tag. I set it to 0 for `h=` and `n=`.  There is still a space after the tag.

I also tried using `padding-bottom` and `margin-bottom` but both of those don't work either.

As a note, the `p` tag is added automatically using the WordPress function `wpautop`.  However, I tried putting the paragraph tags in manually and not using that function and it had the same effect.

Edit: to include surrounding `p` tags.

Comment: This sounds like a styling question no really related to PHP to TCPDF. Try setting margins and padding to zero for the `div` and making it inline instead of block which is the default using `<div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; display: inline;">`.

Comment: I just tried that solution now, it didn't work for me.

Comment: I just edited my comment, forgot the semi-colon after the padding and display values.

Comment: I just tried that with the updated code. It didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Set the position using either

```
$pdf->SetY(25); or $this->SetXY(130,20);
```

or using in-line styling on the DOM element

```
<span style="position: absolute; top: -4px; left: 16px;">test</span>
```

Comment: It is within a larger block of text, so I don't think that will work.

Comment: have you tried using in-line styling on the dom element?